# Why this C++ program should crash runtime?

Tags: c++, arrays, debugging

I am newbie in C++ and I am trying to write a program in C++. Below is my code. When it comes to the lines indicated by comment `//PROGRAM crashes` ,  the program crashes and gives this error: `Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    double simTime = 5;
    double r = 0.9;
    double t, F = 1;
    int i, counter = 0;
    int n = 100;

    double* u_n = new double[n];
    double* u_n_minus_one = new double[n];
    double* u_n_plus_one = new double[n];

    for (i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        u_n[i]=0;
        u_n_minus_one[i]=0;
        u_n_plus_one[i]=0;
    }

    std::ofstream fw1("Values.txt");
    assert(fw1.is_open());

    for (t = 0; t <= simTime; t = t + 0.5)
    {
        for (i = 1; i <= (n-2); i++)
        {
            u_n_plus_one[i] =  pow(r, 2) * (u_n[i-1] + u_n[i+1]) + 2 * (1 - pow(r, 2)) * u_n[i] -u_n_minus_one[i];
        }

        u_n_plus_one[0] = 0;
        u_n_plus_one[int(floor((n)/2))] = F;
        u_n_plus_one[n-1] = 0;

        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            u_n_minus_one[i] = u_n[i];
        }

        for (i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            u_n[i] = u_n_plus_one[i];
        }

        fw1.precision(6);

        //PROGRAM crashes here.
        for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            fw1 << u_n_plus_one[i] << '\t';
        }

        fw1 << std::endl;

        fw1.close();

        delete[] u_n; delete[] u_n_plus_one; delete[] u_n_minus_one;
    }
}
```

I found this crash location with Code::Blocks debugger. Basically, when I try to  I tried debugging further, that is to get the contents of array `u_n_plus_one`, program crashes. 
Code::Blocks debugger does not seem to give contents of array. I have following specific questions associated with this program.

1. What exactly is causing failure and how to debug this?
2. If I want to get contents of array in Code::Blocks, can I get that? That means, if an array has only 4 elements, can I get list of all 4 or if an array has 1000 elements, can I get just element at 50th location?
3. Can I do variable manipulations in debugger? I mean, in MATLAB if I am debugging, I can enter a command in command window, say A+B and get result. Is it possible with C++?

I would highly appreciate any help.

Comment: Please read and follow [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @usar, I am really not able to find the reason with debugger. That is the reason I posted my question here.

Comment: @Deduplicator deleted some stuff from original program to create a minimal.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is very simple. You are closing your file and disposing of all varibles while still inside the loop `for (t=0;t<=simTime;t=t+0.5)`.

First time you go through the loop is ok, second time you are invoking undefined behaviour when using all those variables that have been deleted and trying to write to a closed file.

All of this would have been easy to detect if you had indented your code properly. Looks matter!

Comment: Your solution Works. Can you comment on my questions 2 and 3?

Comment: 2. I don't know anything about Code::Blocks; 3. Technically its possible but I don't know of any debugger that would let you do that. I suggest you put those on new, separate questions.

Answer (score 1):

You are deleting variables and closing fw1 within the for loop. You probably intended:

```
}

delete[] u_n; delete[] u_n_plus_one; delete[] u_n_minus_one;
fw1.close();
```

}